# Empty params on Twiml POST request

Tags: node.js, rest, meteor, twilio, twilio-twiml

A little background. I have a web app running that is attempting to receive incoming texts from Twilio. I have configured Twilio's sms twiml url to point to a route in my app at:

`http://my-app-name.com/api/twiml`

I have some code executed when the request has been made:

```
if (Meteor.server) {
    // use picker to make a server side route
    Picker.route('/api/twiml', (params, req, res, next) => {
        console.log(util.inspect(params, {showHidden: true, colors: true}));
        console.log(util.inspect(req.body, {showHidden: true, colors: true}));

        // message data (not populating?)
        let messageSid = params.query.MessageSid,
            accountSid = params.query.AccountSid,
            from = params.query.From,
            to = params.query.To,
            body = params.query.Body;

        //console.log(messageSid + '\n' + accountSid + '\n' + from + '\n' + to + '\n' + body)

        //from = '+' + from.trim();
        //to = '+' + to.trim();

        let responseBody = 'Thanks';

        res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'});

        return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Sms from="[TWILIOFROM]" to="[TO]">[BODY]</Sms></Response>'
            .replace('[TWILIOFROM]', myNumber)
            .replace('[TO]', from)
            .replace('[BODY]', responseBody);
    });
}
```

When I text my twilio number the code runs but I'm getting a `11200 HTTP retrieval failure` error in my Twilio logs. My app's logs are outputting the first `console.log`'s but I'm not receiving any data from my `params.query`.

`{ query: {} }`

The second console.log: `console.log(util.inspect(req.body, {showHidden: true, colors: true}));` spits out some garbage: `[90mundefined[39m`

Should I give up parameters and try to parse the request body?

I'm very new to REST api's so I'm sure that I'm missing something pretty basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When Twilio POSTs to your configured SMS url, the [parameters are sent as the body of the request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request), not as query string parameters.

I'm not too familiar with Picker, but the [documentation suggests you can use Express middleware](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker#middlewares), including `body-parser`. If you hook up Picker with `body-parser` then you should be able to get the parameters from `req.body`. Something like this might work (note lines 2 and 3, including `body-parser`):

```
if (Meteor.server) {
    var bodyParser = Meteor.npmRequire( 'body-parser');
    Picker.middleware( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) );

    // use picker to make a server side route
    Picker.route('/api/twiml', (params, req, res, next) => {
        console.log(util.inspect(params, {showHidden: true, colors: true}));
        console.log(util.inspect(req.body, {showHidden: true, colors: true}));

        // message data (not populating?)
        let messageSid = req.body.MessageSid,
            accountSid = req.body.AccountSid,
            from = req.body.From,
            to = req.body.To,
            body = req.body.Body;

        //console.log(messageSid + '\n' + accountSid + '\n' + from + '\n' + to + '\n' + body)

        //from = '+' + from.trim();
        //to = '+' + to.trim();

        let responseBody = 'Thanks';

        res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'});

        let twiml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Sms from="[TWILIOFROM]" to="[TO]">[BODY]</Sms></Response>'
            .replace('[TWILIOFROM]', myNumber)
            .replace('[TO]', from)
            .replace('[BODY]', responseBody);

        res.end(twiml);
    });
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

**EDIT**: I think that, instead of returning the TwiML, you actually need to send it to the response object with `res.send`. I've updated the code above.

Comment: This totally helped thank you so much! I am still getting a `11200 HTTP retrieval failure`. Im guessing my response is incorrect?

Comment: So, are you seeing the incoming parameters in the request body now?

Comment: Yes Im able to see the req.body parameters.

Comment: I think you need to `res.send(twiml)` instead of returning it. See my edit.

Comment: Im getting a type error when using `res.send`. `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'send'`. Maybe put it in res.end?

Comment: Ack, yes, sorry I'm just thinking of Express. Try it with `res.end` that should work.

Comment: You da man! Thanks for helping me! Im getting the data I need and the `res.end` is sending a text back with no errors from either my app nor twilio. Good day to you sir!

Comment: Boom! That's awesome it's working. Feel like we got through this together. Good luck with the rest of the app!